# Javascript Dynamic Accordion Help needed

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have my mock up here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzMpga?editors=0010

I need help in making the last column as clickable button and on the click(action), the hierarchy of the employee should expand in the first column.

Also, if you could guide me how to get the that +/- icon on the button click if it has a parent

```
function createAccordion(oneEmployee) {
  var returnValues = [];
  var accordionButton = document.createElement("button");
  accordionButton.className = "accordion";
  accordionButton.setAttribute("value", oneEmployee.resolverGroups);
  accordionButton.setAttribute("onClick", "populateResolverGroups('"+oneEmployee.resolverGroups+"', '" + oneEmployee.employee + "')");

  watchingRGs[oneEmployee.employee] = oneEmployee.resolverGroups;
  watchResolverGroup("", oneEmployee.employee);

  var accordionTextNode = document.createTextNode(oneEmployee.employee);
  accordionButton.appendChild(accordionTextNode);
  returnValues[0] = accordionButton;
  var accordionDiv = document.createElement("div");
  accordionDiv.className = "panel";
  if (oneEmployee.reports.length > 0) {
    for (var empInd = 0; empInd < oneEmployee.reports.length; empInd++) {
      var thisEmpAcc = createAccordion(oneEmployee.reports[empInd]);
      accordionDiv.appendChild(thisEmpAcc[0]);
      accordionDiv.appendChild(thisEmpAcc[1]).click();
    }
  }
  returnValues[1] = accordionDiv;
  if(oneEmployee.resolverGroups.length > 0 ) {
  accordionButton.click(); 
  }
  return returnValues;
}

function populateResolverGroups(resolverGroups, employeeName) {
  document.getElementById('resolvergroups').innerHTML = "";
  var rgList = resolverGroups.split(',');
  for (var rgInd = 0; rgInd < rgList.length; rgInd++) {
    var cbox = document.createElement('input');
   cbox.setAttribute("onclick", "watchResolverGroup('"+rgList[rgInd]+"', '"+employeeName+"')");
    cbox.type = "checkbox";
    cbox.name = rgList[rgInd]; 
    cbox.value = rgList[rgInd];
    cbox.id = rgList[rgInd];

    //cbox.checked = true;
    //keeps track of the RGs that are checked
    if (watchingRGs[employeeName] !== undefined) {
    if (watchingRGs[employeeName].includes(rgList[rgInd])) {
        cbox.checked = true;
      }
    }   
    var cboxTextNode = document.createTextNode(rgList[rgInd]);
    var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
    document.getElementById('resolvergroups').appendChild(cbox);
    document.getElementById('resolvergroups').appendChild(cboxTextNode);
    document.getElementById('resolvergroups').appendChild(linebreak);

  }
}


function watchResolverGroup(resolverGroupName, employeeName) {
  var selectedRGs = [];
  if (watchingRGs[employeeName] !== undefined) {
    selectedRGs = watchingRGs[employeeName];
  }
  if (resolverGroupName.length > 0) {
    if (selectedRGs.includes(resolverGroupName)) {
      selectedRGs.splice(selectedRGs.indexOf(resolverGroupName), 1);
    } else {
      selectedRGs.push(resolverGroupName);
    }
  }
  watchingRGs[employeeName] = selectedRGs;

  document.getElementById("selected_resolvergroups").innerHTML = "";
  for (var key in watchingRGs) {
    var val = watchingRGs[key];
    for (var rgInd = 0; rgInd < val.length; rgInd++) {
      var tempTextNode = document.createTextNode(val[rgInd] + " -> " + key);
      var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
      document.getElementById("selected_resolvergroups").appendChild(tempTextNode);
      document.getElementById("selected_resolvergroups").appendChild(linebreak);
    }
  }
}
```

How to proceed with that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WzMpga?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

For Open Close Hiracrhy this will help you

http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html
[Example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html)

If you want to build your own take a look at this fiddle it will help

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/5/)

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
        <td><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
        <td><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I added to the Css. This is my first time trying the UI stuff.
I am not sure on where to put the toggle as my buttons are created in Js.

Comment: you need to add that css and js to the element .you are creating DIVs in js and adding elements to it , rather do create that table strucutre and then the JS will add the image of +,- hirarchy to it .